# SQLAlchemy - Error which accessing json column

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to cross join on jsonb column and getting exception message - "DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue) cannot call jsonb_each on a non-object"

Below is the code which I am using. This query works perfectly when execute as SQL from psql.

```
stmt = text("select b.user_uuid from audit.audit_logs b cross join jsonb_each(b.data) as t2 where b.status = :x")
stmt = stmt.bindparams(x="FAILURE")
rs= db_operation.session.execute(stmt).all()
```

Stack trace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidParameterValue                     Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\work\notebook\pipeline_notebook\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1900, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1899     if not evt_handled:
-> 1900         self.dialect.do_execute(
   1901             cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1902         )
   1904 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

File c:\work\notebook\pipeline_notebook\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:736, in DefaultDialect.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    735 def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 736     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

InvalidParameterValue: cannot call jsonb_each on a non-object
```

Any idea how to fix it?
SQLAlchemy Version: 1.4.46